# JetBrains IDEs: move cursor inside closest parentheses

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Let's imagine that my cursor is at [0] position and I want to move on to [1] position (the closest parentheses). How can I do that really quick in IntelliJ or any other JetBrains' product?

Of course with <kbd>CTRL + ARROWS</kbd> it's fast but I think there is a lack of such shortcut. If not tell me :)

```
//HTML
<section [0] id="home-icons" class="py-5">[1]</section>
//Java
String param[0]etres = new BufferedReader([1]);
```

Comment: There is no shortcut specifically for jumping to the closest parenthesis (and I'm not aware of any other editor which has such a shortcut).

Comment: @yole Wouldn't  be that helpful ? How do you think?

Comment: I don't quite understand why this specific action deserves a dedicated shortcut. This doesn't seem to be a very common operation.

Comment: Maybe try **AceJump plugin**? Have not used myself .. but it may help here (saw videos/gifs of how it works: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086-acejump).

Comment: This particular use case may not be that common, but I do see added value for a somewhat more advanced version of <kbd>CTRL+ARROWS</kbd>. Which instead of just doing some camel jumps, will put the cursor on more strategic places based on the context. Like inside next attribute.

Comment: In case of empty single-line HTML attributes the Next Emmet Edit Point action should do what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, press Ctrl+Shift+M.
For more info:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-braces.html

Comment: I've tried that, it works similarly to Ctrl + Shift + [ ]. It's not about what I mentioned here.